# This is adding 2 strings when i am trying to add to intergers?

Tags: javascript

**This is returning 2 strings when i am trying to a 2 intergers.** this is probably a really easy question!
thanks

```
<script>
function add() {
var noO = prompt("please enter a number:");
var noT = prompt("please enter a second number:");
var no1 = noO;
var no2 = noT;
var res = no1 + no2;
alert("the adiition of thoes 2 numbers is: " + res);
}
</script>
```

Comment: prompt returns a string ... try `Number(prompt("..."))`

Comment: I think you need to parse `no1` and `no2` so JS recognises them as integers: `parseInt(no1) + parseInt(no2);`

Comment: try [`parseFloat(prompt())`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwic1taF5ZTUAhUIro8KHVxSDJcQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_parsefloat.asp&usg=AFQjCNHnX2N78WPvEGHs8qefO1xV4Wm98A&sig2=iBmjlPnhrnZFy1MYWupYKQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [parseInt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) on `no1` and `no2` like follows:

```js
  var noO = prompt("please enter a number:");
  var noT = prompt("please enter a second number:");
  var no1 = noO;
  var no2 = noT;
  var res = parseInt(no1, 10) + parseInt(no2, 10);
  alert("the adiition of thoes 2 numbers is: " + res);
```

---

### EDIT

In addition, it is probably worth noting that `parseInt` should always be used with a `radix` specified based on the required behaviour:

> An integer between 2 and 36 that represents the radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems) of the above mentioned string. Specify 10 for the decimal numeral system commonly used by humans. Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified, usually defaulting the value to 10

E.g. a radix of 10 indicates to convert from a decimal number, 8 octal, 16 hexadecimal.. There are many examples on the web page link above.

Answer (score 0):

```
function add() {
  var noO = parseInt(prompt("please enter a number:"));
  var noT = parseInt(prompt("please enter a second number:"));
  var no1 = noO;
  var no2 = noT;
  var res = no1 + no2;
  alert("the adiition of thoes 2 numbers is: " + res);
}
```

Comment: Please add a short explanation to your post, what your code does and why it solves the initial problem. Don't just post a block of uncommented code.

Comment: Sure!.. prompt alway's will return a String  i just convert that String into Integer. so it solves the initial problem